# Moving from ef 6 to ef core (Navigation properties)

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-core, navigation-properties

Fist of all sorry for my English )
I has an application which uses odata service.
This data service is with ef 6 and edmx model.
And I want to create another data service by ef core.
In current data service some models have navigation properties which was renamed.
And now application has naviganion properties (for ef 6 from edmx) but in ef core data service its have another names.
Is there any method to rename navigation properties in ef core data service based on edmx model?

Comment: The best way of updating is to use Migration.  Migration will create a new mapping file (replaces the edmx mapping file) from the c# classes.  The new names should be added to the c# classes.  The mapping file is used to map the c# classes properties to the database tables/fields.  See  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/ and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/entity-properties?tabs=data-annotations%2Cwithout-nrt